# Outlining in Blender?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, edit-mode, image

I am currently working on converting my logo vectored as a SVG to a 3D model using the 2.72 version. I ran into a problem with my logo because it contains a black stroke and an orange stroke (see both images below), but currently all I have is the interior color of each shape. I was wondering whether or not there was a simple way to add in these strokes, and how exactly to go about creating the strokes. Thank you in advance community! [image: as you can see the logo contains two different strokes] [image: My current workflow]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest way I can think of, is to go back to the program where you created the logo and make sure to have different paths/vectors for each of its parts. Then just export the SVG and import it in blender...

[image]

Comment: That was exactly what I needed to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The SVG importer will ignore stroke thickness property, which means you have to convert strokes to paths in external vector editor such as AI or Inkscape, then you can edit curves much more conveniently within Blender.

Answer (score 1):

While of course it is always **better to use the original SVG-data** (see accepted solution), there is another method if this cannot be found or generated for a particular picture. This option makes use of the displacement modifier:

From A (original Image), make a version like B) in your favorite image manipulation tool. Then go in blender, add a plane, add a few subdivisions (with subdivision mofifier) and add a displacement modifier. Set B.) as the displacement texture and Apply all modifiers. Then delete the lower plane (with box select). Then make a material with a node setup as seen in E.) with the image texture of A.). 
And you're done!

[image: Outline if svg method not possible]

Happy Blending!