# Cutting mesh by projecting texture

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, uv, orthographic

I wanna create 2D image with Blender. I have an identical image as a template. Can I project my template somehow on a plane mesh to cut it and get specific and save some time instead of outlining it manually?

P.S. Need to carve this pie on this circle mesh. ________________________
 [image: Pie] [image: Circle]

Comment: Would be helpful if you could add the image to the question. Generally, I'd suggest to trace the image in a vector graphics app such as Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator, save it as an SVG file, then import that SVG as a curve object to Blender.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, you can fake it by using a texture with transparency and making parts of the mesh invisible. But if you want to actually cut the geometry you won't be able to do it easily from an image alone. Ither trace it with a vector drafting application and import as SVG, or manually trace it in Blender

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51792/how-can-i-model-gothic-style-windows/51904#51904 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17952/outlining-in-blender

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using the Displace modifier.

1. Subdivide the circle a few times to ensure it has enough polygons to displace
2. UV unwrap the circle and apply the texture to it, ensuring it fits nicely to the circle
3. Add a Displace modifier, using the texture, and selecting the correct UV map in the modifier settings, this should give you something like this (I used your example image, but the original will probably look better)
   [image]
4. Apply all modifiers and go into edit mode, then select all vertices that are not on the ground plane and delete them. (press `B` to select vertices and then press `Numpad 1` to go into side view, also you'll want to turn `Limit selection to visible` off, which can be found on the header of the 3d view at the bottom)
   [image]
5. Cleanup the result by selecting all vertices and pressing `S` `Z` `0` `Enter` to make all resulting vertices flat to the ground. Also you could add  a Decimate modifier, or cleanup a bit manually.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. unless you import it as line art of some form like svg.

I would say your best bet is to model from the top view and extrude verticies along the outlines of the image and fill the resulting edges with faces....
afterwards you can extrude the faces and apply a boolean modifer to the other mesh to cut out the shape.