# I want to make a mesh with the shape of the transparency of a PNG image

Tags: mesh

I want to create the shape of the png image excluding the alpha as an object.
This means arranging the vertices to follow the outline of the image(like text objects).
Could you teach me if there is a good method or add-on that will process it automatically?

Comment: could you show some pictures please?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17952/outlining-in-blender https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1609/tracing-a-monochrome-image-into-a-3d-extruded-object-with-a-script

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. And thank you for your comments. I was embarrassed to know how to handle SVG data in Blender for the first time. I was not good at finding similar questions...