# convert jpeg image to 2d stroke

Tags: animation, 2d

I'm new for blender and I'm searching or any advice as solution for my question. my question is, Is there any system or any tool that we can use to transfer jpeg image file to 2d animation stroke file. currently im using images as reference and creating stroke layers on it. but when it come to create the faces my out come of drawing was terrible. so please advice how I can fix this.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17952/outlining-in-blender/17954#17954

Comment: Load the image into a vector drawing app, like inkscape or illustrator. There are tools to "trace" the raster image to make a "path", save as .svg and import that into blender. The resulting image will be a curve object in blender, that can be easily converted to a stroke.